# How to maintain Pause Button in fancybox

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, fancybox

```
I would like to maintain pause button active when I click on autoplay button

You can see it in JSfiddle: 

http://jsfiddle.net/v6hha


    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect: "elastic",
        openSpeed: 100,
        closeEffect: "elastic",
        closeSpeed: 100,
        prevEffect: "none",
        prevSpeed: 100,
        nextEffect: "none",
        nextSpeed: 100,
        minWidth: "130px",
        padding: 5,
        closeBtn: false,
        helpers: {
            title: {
                type: "inside",
                position: "top"
            },
            overlay: {
                locked: false
            }
        },
        afterLoad: function () {
            if (this.group.length > 1) {
                this.title = ' Рисунок ' + (this.index + 1) + " из " + this.group.length + (this.title ? " - " + this.title : "")
            }
            if (this.group.length  Рисунок ' + (this.index + 1) + " из " + this.group.length + (this.title ? " - " + this.title : "")
            }
        },
        afterShow: function () {
            $(".fancybox-wrap").easydrag();
            var e;
            e = $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnPlay").removeClass("btnPlayOn");
            if ($.fancybox.player.isActive) {
                e.addClass("btnPlayOn")
            }
            var t;
            t = $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnToggle").removeClass("btnDisabled btnToggleOn");
            if (this.canShrink) {
                t.addClass("btnToggleOn")
            } else if (!this.canExpand) {
                t.addClass("btnDisabled")
            }
        },
        onPlayStart: function () {
            $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnPlay").addClass("btnPlayOn")
        },
        onPlayEnd: function () {
            $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnPlay").removeClass("btnPlayOn")
        },
        onUpdate: function () {
            var e;
            e = $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnToggle").removeClass("btnDisabled btnToggleOn");
            if (this.canShrink) {
                e.addClass("btnToggleOn")
            } else if (!this.canExpand) {
                e.addClass("btnDisabled")
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Try disabling t = $("#fancybox-buttons").find(".btnToggle").removeClass("btnDisabled btnToggleOn");

Comment: Can u show me it in JSfiddle ? OR please paste full Javascript code here..

Comment: You do realize that Java is not JavaScript, right?

Comment: when I clicked on autoplay.. Pause button disappearing.. we can see only play button.. But slide show working without any problem.. see this screenshot.. http://i.imgur.com/ZIQop9f.png

Comment: Please see it in JsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/v6hha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kindly remove this line

```
$(".fancybox-wrap").easydrag();
```

When I've tried on chrome an error is coming on this step that easydrag() is not available.
After removing it control works properly. Kindly check...